# Gridview is not displaying footer?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here I had given `"Showfooter"=true` property but still it's not displaying
But while debug value(sumofamount) is  assign to label.text

My GridView Code:

```
      <asp:GridView ID="gvGrossDetails" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
          CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="1" CssClass="grid_bg" GridLines="None" DataKeyNames="Code"
          OnRowEditing="gvPayeeGross_RowEditing" OnRowDeleting="gvGrossDetails_RowDeleting"
          OnRowUpdating="gvGrossDetails_RowUpdating" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvGrossDetails_RowCancelingEdit"
          PagerStyle-Width="0px" PageSize="10" ShowFooter="true" Width="112%" Style="margin-top: 0px">
<PagerStyle CssClass="hide" />
<SelectedRowStyle CssClass="tble_hdr_not_sltd" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="tble_hdr_not_sltd" />
<EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="row_odd" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<FooterStyle CssClass="hide" />
<RowStyle CssClass="row_even" />
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table class="confirmation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label Text="Records not found" ID="lblEmpty" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="row_odd" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPayeeID1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Code") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="0%" />
            <HeaderStyle />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPayeeCode" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Code") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="0%" />
            <HeaderStyle />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Account head
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblGrossType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Accounthead") %>' Wrap="true"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="item_Style1" />
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="middle" width="50%">

                            <asp:Label ID="txtGrossType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Accounthead")%>'
                                CssClass="black_normal"   Width="110px"></asp:Label>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="20%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="13%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                Payee Amount
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPresentedAmount" runat="server" Text=' <%# Eval("PayeeAmount")%>' Wrap="true"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle CssClass="item_Style1" />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                <asp:Label ID="txtPresentedAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PayeeAmount")%>'
                                    CssClass="black_normal" onblur="requiredCheck(this);" MaxLength="5" Width="110px"></asp:Label>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:Label Text=Text='<%# GetTotalSalary() %>'  ID="lbltotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>

                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="13%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="13%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    Approved Amount
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblApproveAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ApprovedAmount")%>'
                        Wrap="true"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle CssClass="item_Style1" />
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="middle">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtApproveAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ApprovedAmount")%>'
                                    CssClass="black_normal" onblur="requiredCheck(this);" MaxLength="5" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="fltrApprove" runat="server" FilterType="Custom"
                                    FilterMode="InvalidChars" InvalidChars="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@!#$%^&*%<> ,"
                                    TargetControlID="txtApproveAmount">
                                </ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="approrve" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="13%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="6%">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="cursor: pointer;
                        cursor: hand;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" style="display: none" valign="middle">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" width="70%">
                                            <a>Delete</a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 6px">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle">
                                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="left" width="70%">
                                            <a>Delete</a>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="width: 6px">
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left: 3px">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" height="19px" valign="middle">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSEdit" CssClass="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" UseSubmitBehavior="false"
                                    CausesValidation="false" />

                            </td>
                            <td align="right" height="19px" valign="middle">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSDelete" CssClass="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="delete"
                                    UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="false" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right" valign="middle" nowrap>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSUpdate" CssClass="btnUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update"
                                    UseSubmitBehavior="false" ValidationGroup="GSave" CausesValidation="false" />
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSCancel" CssClass="btnCancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"
                                    UseSubmitBehavior="false" CausesValidation="false" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemStyle Width="6%" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

sumof total

```
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Separator)
    {
        total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "GrossAmount"));
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow || e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Separator)
    {
        total += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ApprovedAmount"));
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        Label lblamount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblgrossamount");
        lblamount.Text = total.ToString();
    }
```

Here i had given "Showfooter"=true property but still it's not displaying
 But while debug value(sumofamount) is  assign to label.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line apply css for the gridview infooter:

```
<FooterStyle CssClass="hide" />
```

i think that this can hide the footr of gridview pls check this css...

Comment: hi thanks for reply, it's helped me if i want to sum for two or three columns in same grid how to do that?

Comment: like i have two columns of amount gross and deduction) how to calculate both?

Comment: yes i created footer for both the columns and put label also but in codebehind..please check updated code for sumofamount

Comment: how to footer control if it is second column?